# I don't understand the error: this.state.categories.map is not a function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React JS and I'm getting the error that I can't use the map function on a state array i'm using.

I'm currently building a webapp using the Eventbrite api, getting data from the api is not the problem. But when I want to loop through the given data React responds with the error I have given above.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


export default class Categories extends Component {
    state={
        apiUrl : 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103',
        OAuthToken  : 'my OAuthToken',
        loading: true,
        categories: []
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get(`${this.state.apiUrl}?token=${this.state.OAuthToken}`)
            .then(res => {
            let result = res.data;
            this.setState({categories : result});
            console.log(this.state.categories);
            if(this.state.result !== ''){
                this.setState({loading:false});
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    renderCategories(){
        if(this.state.loading === false){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.categories.map(item=> (
                    <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused in what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `result` coming back from your network call is actually an array?

Comment: What does the `console.log()` tell you about the updated value of the `categories` property?

Comment: `res.data` is possibly not an array?

Comment: Ah the problem was that it isn't an array. Stupid me got clumsy. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The `.map` function only works on array-like variables. If that's the actual endpoint that you're calling then from [the documentation](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api/#/reference/categories/retrieve/retrieve-a-category) it looks like it's not returning an array but an Object in the following format:

```
{
  "id": "103",
  "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/",
  "name": "Music",
  "name_localized": "Music",
  "short_name": "Music",
  "short_name_localized": "Music",
  "subcategories": [
    {
      "id": "3003",
      "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/3003/",
      "name": "Classical",
      "parent_category": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to iterate through the keys or values you can turn that Object into an array using `Object.keys(result)` or `Object.values(result)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this with fetch()...

```
fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizers/{organizer_id}/events/?status=live&token=******')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => gatherData(data.events))

function gatherData(data) {
  const options = data.map(item => `
  <div id="event-contain">  
    <div class="event-left" style="width: 66%;"> 
      <img src="${item.logo.url}">
      <a href="${item.url}"><h5>${item.name.html}</h5></a><br/>
      <p>${item.description.text}</p>
      <a href="${item.url}"><button style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 15px;">Buy Tickets</button></a><br/><br/>
      <div class="spacer" style="width: 100%; height: 30px; border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `).join('');
  evdis.innerHTML = options;
}
```

It seems like you are missing a step in setting a variable to the JSON response. You should then be able to enter into the highest state of the JSON response ( aka events ) This will allow you to iterate through all of the events that you own using .map and display those events.

I hope this helps. 
Best of luck!